# stdlib not working in nxtOSEK

Tags: c++, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I am programming the Lego Nxt Brick with nxtOSEK in C++. It seems that the stdlib.h library is not working, but the string.h library works fine. Has anyone seen this before?

my includes

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

my error

```
LegoQueue.cpp: In function ‘void queue::debugstring(char*)’:
LegoQueue.cpp:131: error: ‘itoa’ was not declared in this scope
```

Even though the c++ documentation for itoa (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) clearly states that itoa should be in stdlib.h, itoa is not declared. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No, the documentation you link to clearly states the exact opposite. "Portability: This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers."

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling your code as C++, you should prefer to write your include directives this way:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
```

Please let me know if it helps.